# Nominalizer vs te-form: which to use when subordinate to 望む?

Tags: nuances, syntax, て-form

The following are some song lyrics

> あなたが望むなら
> この胸を射通して

What's the difference between

> あなたがこの胸を射通すの望むなら

And

> あなたがこの胸を射通して望むなら

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use ～するのを望む or ～することを望む when the wish itself is that verb. ～して望む means something different.

- あなたが望むなら この胸を射通して
  If you wish (it), shoot through this heart!
  <sub>(Shooting is a request; the wish can be either shooting or something different)</sub>
- あなたがこの胸を射通すの(を)望むなら
  If you wish to shoot through this heart...
  <sub>(を is omitted after の; shooting is the wish itself)</sub>
- あなたがこの胸を射通して望むなら
  If you wish it penetrating through this heart...
  <sub>(Shooting is a method of making the wish, and the wish itself is something different)</sub>